# alert box not stopping execution/submission of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a code snippet I'm using. Here as per my expectation, code execution doesn't stop and the form gets submitted. Though alert box appears but after pressing "ok" the form get submitted.

```
$('.qto').each(function(index) {        
    if (jQuery.inArray($("#quota-" + (index + 1)).val(), quoatas) != -1) {
        alert("Please check the different values you have entered");
        return false;
    }
    quoatas.push($("#quota-" + (index + 1)).val());
});
```

Comment: Where are you submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your `return false` is relevant to the anonymous function it's contained in, not the `submit` handler of the form (which I'm presuming this code is contained within). As a workaround, you can use the `preventDefault()` method of the `event` which is passed to the submit handler. Try this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    $('.qto').each(function(index) {        
        if ($.inArray($("#quota-" + (index + 1)).val(), quoatas) != -1) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission
            alert("Please check the different values you have entered");
        }
        quoatas.push($("#quota-" + (index + 1)).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use preventDefault() to stop form submission
```

Comment: Please add code and explain how preventDefault() stops the form submission

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use event handler which is bound to the form like this,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Submit Handler</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Enter 'demo' as valid data: </p>
<form id="formId" action="javascript:alert( 'Value Valid. Form submitted.' );">
  <div>
    <input id="firstName" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Check">
  </div>
</form>
<p id="response" style="color:red;"></p>
 
<script>
$( "#formId" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "#firstName" ).val() === "demo" ) {
    $( "#response" ).empty();
    $( "#response" ).text( "Submitted." ).show();
    return;
  }
  $( "#response" ).empty();
  $( "#response" ).append( "Not submitted." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```